# How to get a for loop more readable in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am looking for a way to make a for loop in bash more readable.

For example

```
for test in lalala kakaka jajaja hahaha
do
echo $test
done
```

would be

```
for test in 
{
lalala
kakaka
jajaja
hahaha
}

do
echo $test
done
```

I know I can put these parameters in a different file, but I really want to keep those parameters in the same script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options: use line continuations

```sh
for test in \
    lalala \
    kakaka \
    jajaja \
    hahaha
do
    echo "$test"
done
```

Or assign to an array first:

```sh
tests=(
    lalala
    kakaka
    jajaja
    hahaha
)

for test in "${tests[@]}"; do
    echo "$test"
done
```